# Finding personal information in documents (hard problem)

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am tasked with trying to create an automated system that removes personal information from text documents.

Emails, phone numbers are relatively easy to remove. Names are not. The problem is hard because there are names in the documents that need to be kept (eg, references, celebrities, characters etc).  The author name needs to be removed from the content (there may also be more than one author).

I have currently thought of the following:

- Quite often personal names are located at the beginning of a document
- Look at how frequently the name is used in the document (personal names tend to be written just once)
- Search for words around the name to find patterns (mentions of university and so on...)

Any ideas? Anyone solved this problem already??

Comment: Do a Google search for the name?

Answer (score 1):

With current technology, doing what what you are describing in a fully automated way with a low error rate is impossible.

It might be possible to come up with an approximate solution, but it would still make a lot of errors...... either false positives or false negatives or some combination of the two.

If you are still really determined to try, I think your best approach would be Bayseian filtering ([as used in spam filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)). The reason for this is that it is quite good at assigning probabilities based on relative positions and frequencies of words, and could also learn which names are more likely / less likely to be celebrities etc.

Answer (score 0):

The area of machine learning that you would need to learn about to make an attempt at this would be natural language processing. There are a few different approaches that could be used, bayesian networks (something better then a naive bayes classifier), support vector machines, or neural nets would be areas to research. Whatever system you end up building would probably need to use an annotated corpus (labeled set of data) to learn where names should be. Even with a large corpus, whatever you build will not be 100% accurate, so you would probably be better off setting flags at the names for deletion instead of just deleting all of the words that might be names.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in basic cryptography courses (my first programming job).

If you generated a ***word histogram*** of your entire document corpus (each bin is a word on the x-axis whose height is frequency represented by height on the y-axis), words like "this", "the", "and" and so forth would be easy to identify because of their large y-values (frequency). Surnames should at the far right of your histogram--very infrequent; given names towards the left, but not by much.

Does this technique definitively identify the names in each document? No, but it could be used to substantially constrain your search, by eliminating *all words whose frequency is larger than X*. Likewise, there should be other attributes that constrain your search, such as author names only appear once on the documents they authored and not on any other documents.